# Storing property to multiple columns using iBatis

Tags: ibatis

I'm looking for solution of the following situation. Let's say I have a business object Vector referencing class/structure Point.

```
class Vector{
 int id;
 Point begin;
 Point end;
}

class Point {
 int x;
 int y;
}
```

What I want to do is to save the begin and end to the same table as the vector itself.

```
table Vectors {
 int id;
 int begin_x;
 int begin_y;
 int end_x;
 int end_y;
}
```

I know this from the Hibernate world as Component Mapping, but I was unable to find similar concept for iBatis. Is there a way to express this functionality in iBatis mapping files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your DAO, assume that you will be using (g/s)etters on objects

```
    public void saveVector(Vector v) throws DataAccessException
    {
        Map params = new HashMap();
        params.put("id",new Integer(v.id);
        params.put("begin_x",new Integer(v.begin.x);
        params.put("begin_y",new Integer(v.begin.y);
        params.put("end_x",new Integer(v.end.x);
        params.put("end_y",new Integer(v.end.y);
        getSqlMapClientTemplate().insert("Vectors.insertVectors", params);
    }
```

In mapping file

```
    <insert id="insertVectors" parameterClass="java.util.Map">
        INSERT INTO
        Vectors(id,begin_x,begin_y,end_x,end_y)
        VALUES
        (#id#,#begin_x#,#begin_y#,#end_x#,#end_y#)
    </insert>
```